# How to properly run a function on an object and how to properly use .apply() to run a method on an object?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm having trouble getting this to run properly. I'm close but things are just the opposite of what I need them to be. Any help with this and maybe a little more explanation of what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

I am given a the function `checkOut` and two objects `book1` and `book2`.

```js
function checkOut() {
  this.available = !this.available;
  return `"${this.title}" is ${this.available ? '' : 'not '}available for check-out.`;
}

var book1 = {
  title: 'One Fish, Two Fish, Red Fish, Blue Fish',
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false,
  checkOut: checkOut
};

var book2 = {
  title: "Oh, the Places You'll Go!",
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false
};

var book2CheckOut = checkOut.bind(book2);
console.log(book2CheckOut);

var book2CheckOut2 = book1.checkOut.apply(book2);
console.log(book2CheckOut2);
```

I am first supposed to run the function `checkOut` on `book2` and save it to a variable `book2CheckOut`.

Here is what I am trying for that:

```
var book2CheckOut = checkOut.bind(book2)
```

This should give me the string `"Oh, the Places You'll Go! is available for check-out."` But instead I get `"Oh, the Places You'll Go! is not available for check-out."`

Then I am supposed to use the .apply() method on `book1` checkOut function, run it using `book2` as an argument. Save it to a variable `book2CheckOut2`.

Here is what I am trying for that:

```
var book2CheckOut2 = book1.checkOut.apply(book2)
```

This should give me the string `"Oh, the Places You'll Go! is not available for check-out."` But instead gives me `"Oh, the Places You'll Go! is available for check-out."`

Comment: `book2CheckOut` is not a string at all; it's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am first supposed to run the function `checkOut` on `book2` and save it to a variable `book2CheckOut`.
>
> Here is what I am trying for that:
>
> ```
> var book2CheckOut = checkOut.bind(book2)
> ```

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) doesn't run the function at all. To do that, you'd use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var book2CheckOut = checkOut.apply(book2);
```

You *could* use `bind` for this, but you'd want to call the result, e.g.:

```
var checkOutBook2 = checkOut.bind(book2);
var book2CheckOut = checkOutBook2();
```

or

```
var book2CheckOut = checkOut.bind(book2)();
```

...but there's no point creating the function if you're not going to keep and reuse it.

> Then I am supposed to use the `.apply()` method on `book1 checkOut` function, run it using `book2` as an argument. Save it to a variable `book2CheckOut2`.
>
> Here is what I am trying for that:
>
> ```
> var book2CheckOut2 = book1.checkOut.apply(book2)
> ```

That works just fine once you've got the first part right (because the first call flips the `available` flag). Note that it's exactly like `checkOut.apply(book2)`, you're just getting the function reference from a property on `book1` rather than from the in-scope identifier `checkOut`.

The full sequence:

```js
function checkOut() {
  this.available = !this.available;
  return `"${this.title}" is ${this.available ? '' : 'not '}available for check-out.`;
}

var book1 = {
  title: 'One Fish, Two Fish, Red Fish, Blue Fish',
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false,
  checkOut: checkOut
};

var book2 = {
  title: "Oh, the Places You'll Go!",
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false
};

var book2CheckOut = checkOut.apply(book2);
console.log(book2CheckOut);

var book2CheckOut2 = book1.checkOut.apply(book2);
console.log(book2CheckOut2);
```

Or with the `bind` alternative that we then call:

```js
function checkOut() {
  this.available = !this.available;
  return `"${this.title}" is ${this.available ? '' : 'not '}available for check-out.`;
}

var book1 = {
  title: 'One Fish, Two Fish, Red Fish, Blue Fish',
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false,
  checkOut: checkOut
};

var book2 = {
  title: "Oh, the Places You'll Go!",
  author: 'Dr. Seuss',
  available: false
};

var checkOutBook2 = checkOut.bind(book2);
var book2CheckOut = checkOutBook2();
console.log(book2CheckOut);

var book2CheckOut2 = book1.checkOut.apply(book2);
console.log(book2CheckOut2);
```

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I needed to help me understand what was going on. Thank you so much!